# Identity does not work with facebook authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Like in title, I have problem with facebook and identity. I used microsoft documentation to implement identity and facebook authorization to my project. I can login with identity but when i try login with facebook nothing happens. My client get cookie ("identity.external") but View doesn`t view that user is onlline.

In View I have method:

```
 @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

My controller method for facebook login

```
    public IActionResult SignIn(String provider)
    {
        return Challenge(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, provider);
    }
```

my startup configuration

```
 services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddDbContextPool<StoreContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("StoreDatabase")));

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<StoreContext>();
        services.AddMemoryCache();

        //session
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".MyName";
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            // Make the session cookie essential
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;

        });
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        //session

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = FacebookDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            //options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            //options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddFacebook(options =>
            {
                options.AppId = "CODE";
                options.AppSecret = "CODE";
            }).AddCookie();

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }
        ).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

When I uncomment

```
            //options.DefaultChallengeScheme = FacebookDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        //options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        //options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

Then, facebook work but identity doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using Identity, you don't need to call `AddCookie()` or set any of the default `AuthenticationOptions`. Your `SignIn` method is a little unconventional - this is usually handled by the `ExternalLogin` pages, etc. Can you explain a bit more about why you have this method? You're missing important steps from the external login workflow.

Comment: I was find this method in documentation
[link](http://codereform.com/blog/post/asp-net-core-2-1-authentication-with-social-logins/)

Comment: That article doesn't use Identity, so it misses the link that's needed between Identity and Facebook et al. I'd recommended going through the docs: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) for setting up an Identity project and then [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for adding Facebook. That should help you learn more about how it fits together.

Comment: OK so I'm doing my job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This facebook auth is very complicated.
I post rest of controller method for rest people.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        ExternalLoginInfo info = await signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

        var result = await signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

        }
        else
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email),
                Email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email),
                UserData = new UserData { Email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email) }
            };
            var registrationResult = await userManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (registrationResult.Succeeded)
            {
                registrationResult = await userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
                if (registrationResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("trut Błąd! External provider assocation error");
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("trut błąd! Registration error");
        }

    }
```

and signin method

```
        public IActionResult SignIn(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {

        var properties = signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties("Facebook", Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { returnUrl = returnUrl}));
        return Challenge(properties, "Facebook");

    }
```